# Orthographe disparate d'« étiquette » et « étiquetage »

Tags: étymologie, orthographe

Ces deux mots ont la même origine et pourtant il faut deux *t* à *étiquette* et un seul à *étiquetage*.

Qui peut me dire pourquoi ?

Comment: Je dirais même un seul *t* à *étiqueter*.

Comment: évolution philologique + prononciation (le 'e' de étiquette et étiquetage est différent). Même chose que pour 'appeler'...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La rapide succession d'un [`/ɛ/`](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/API_%C9%9B) (voyelle semi-ouverte : *è*, *ai*) et d'un [`/e/`](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/API_e) (voyelle semi-fermée : é) est un peu difficile en français. Il est assez fréquent qu'un `/e/` transforme une voyelle `/ɛ/` précédente ou suivante en un `/e/` ; par exemple *miette* `/miɛt/` donne *émietter* `/emiete/`, *trait* `/trɛ/` donne *traité* `/trete/`. Je pense que c'est ce phénomène qui explique que le nom *étiquette* `/etikɛt/` a donné le verbe `/etikəte/`, dans lequel la troisième voyelle, difficile à prononcer, se retrouve non accentuée. La prononciation impose donc l'orthographe avec un seul `t`. Le nom *étiquetage* dérive directement du verbe.

Au passage, `-ettage` est une finale rare. Mon correcteur orthographique connaît un seul mot qui l'utilise (*toilettage*), contre 14 en `-etage`. Je ne sais pas si c'est vraiment significatif, vu la diversité des formations (`-et` + `-age`, `-eter` + `-age`, `-e` + `-age` avec `t` euphonique).

Answer (score 5):

L'orthographe de la forme conjuguée de *étiqueter* prend deux *t* (bien que d'après [le wiktionnaire](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wiktionary/fr/wiki/%C3%A9tiqueter#Note) l'Académie l'ait déclarée incorrecte). Je pense qu'un des deux *t* a chuté pour conserver la cohérence entre la prononciation `/etikəte/` et la règle qui veut qu'un *e* non-accentué suivi de de consonnes se prononce `ɛ`.