# How to hear the difference between 'et les gants' and 'élégant'?

Tags: prononciation

I'm trying to understand French by listening, but how does a real Frenchman hear the difference between 'et les gants' and 'élégant'?

As far as I (can) understand, both are pronounced as: ee-lee-gan.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A native speaker will distinguish these most often simply by context. In the rare cases when the context is not useful, the pronunciation is slightly different, so it will still be possible to understand which one was intended.

- *élégant* is pronounced [e.le.gɑ̃]
- *et les gants* is pronounced [e.lɛ.gɑ̃]

Note that the pronunciation of *les* might differ in some regions. In that case, both phrases might sound exactly the same indeed. But again, the context of the conversation is key here.

Comment: I would say that _et les gants_ is usually pronounced [èlégan] where I live.

Comment: Would you happen to know how to write these two pronunciations in IPA? I often have a hard time understanding the difference between é and è (sometimes they sound very distinct to me and other times, such as in this case, they sound exactly the same to me), so perhaps the IPA would be useful to make the distinction clear.

Comment: @bronxbomber92 I absolutely have no knowledge of phonetic notation, so I shamelessly copied them from [Gilles' answer](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/7746/1129) and edited my question.

Comment: @biozic Just out of curiosity, where do you live?

Comment: @bronxbomber92 `é` is always pronounced [e] (close-mid), `è` and `ê` and `e` followed by a double consonant are always pronounced [ɛ] (open-mid), and it depends for `ai` but it's usually [ɛ]. There are exceptions, as the sound can shift, both depending on the speaker and on the context (surrounding sounds, emphasis). In addition some dialects have a single sound (South of France).

Comment: @biozic Oh? Most dictionaries only list the pronounciation [e] for *et* (unlike *est* which is usually pronounced [ɛ]). If anything I would expect [ɛlɛgɑ̃] rather than [elegɑ̃] due to the difficulty of e/ɛ proximity.

Comment: @alexis Burgundy.

Comment: @bronxbomber92 IPA for _et les gants_ in my area would be [ɛ.le.gɑ̃]

Answer (score 8):

They are homophones. Most languages have homophones, French is no exception. The pronunciation is the same: [e.le.gɑ̃]. (Sometimes *les* may be pronounced [lɛ], i.e. with an open è sound instead of the semi-open é sound, but the proximity of the word *et* which is always pronunced with the semi-open sound tends to force *les* to [le].) Usually you can tell from the context.

If you're speaking and you absolutely need to make the difference audible, you can make a slight pause between the words and stress *gants* to indicate *et les gants*, and make a slight pause before the word and stress the first syllable or the first two syllables to indicate *élégant*.

Sometimes, when the phonetic ambiguity is really problematic, French people may resort to spelling orally. For example, *la symétrie* and *l'asymétrie* are antonyms; if there is a risk of confusion, then we could go as far as saying “*la, plus loin, symétrie*” (but more often we would just make a clear pause between *la* and *symétrie*) and “*el apostrophe asymétrie*” (but more often pronouncing [l], then a pause, then *asymétrie*).

Comment: It seems to me that the frequency of [lɛ] is higher than what you imply.  But such estimation are hard to make, first we tend to meet people using the same variants, and then those who make a difference tend to ear it even when it is not done, and those who don't make it tend not to ear it even when it is done.

Comment: @Unfrancophone [Le français tend à éviter /ɛ/ suivi de /e/](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/429/orthographe-disparate-detiquette-et-etiquetage/439#439). Mais c'est vrai qu'ici on a l'inverse, et /e/ suivi de /ɛ/ est plus facile.